# Sublime Text 2/3 class navigation to include class name in methods/fields

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublimetext3

I'm using Sublime Text 3 on a large codebase, the entire LLVM + Clang.
One thing I'm seriously missing is the ability to goto a function belonging to a specific class.

To explain, let's say I'm in a file with 10+ classes, all having a method called `getSourceRange()`.
The current `goto symbol` functionality only indexes the method names, so when I search for this method, I get a bunch of identical results that I have to go through manually until I find the right one. Using the project-wide `Goto Symbol` is worse as there are even more clashes.

What I'd like is for the indexed symbol name to *always* include the class name, e.g. `VarDecl::getSourceRange` instead of just `getSourceRange`. I can enable this for implementations outside-of-class by removing `C++/Symbol Index.tmPreferences` which essentially was stripping the `CLASS::` from the indexed name. However I don't yet know how to inject the class name into definitions that are inside a class' scope.

The information is all there in the TextMate scopes, so I could technically add a rule for the following scope:

```
source.c++  meta.class-struct-block.c++  entity.name.function.c
```

But I don't know how to access the class' name as a string (stored in `meta.class-struct-block.c++ » entity.name.type.c++` as saved in `C++.tmLanguage`), let alone format the function's indexed symbol name to include it.

Anyone know how to do this, if possible? [TextMate's page](http://manual.macromates.com/en/navigation_overview#customizing_the_list) explaining these mechanics doesn't mention this being possible, for what it's worth.

My attempt, stuck at how to insert a syntax name into the `symbol(Index)?Transformation`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>scope</key>
    <string>source.c++ meta.class-struct-block.c++ entity.name.function.c</string>
    <key>settings</key>
    <dict>
        <key>symbolIndexTransformation</key>
        <string>/^/${entity.name.type.c++}::/;</string>
        <key>symbolTransformation</key>
        <string>/^/${entity.name.type.c++}::/;</string> <!-- just adds it literally :( -->
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```